# Storing data in a user specified order

Tags: sql, sorting

I know that in SQL databases data is not stored in a particular order and that ordering is only done via `ORDER BY` statements.

What is the usual approach if I need to store data in a arbitrary order?

Example:

I have names and I want to store them in a certain arbitrary order like:

```
name
-----
foo
hello
bar
```

One approach would be to have an auxiliary field `order` like this:

```
order  name
-----------
1      hello
0      foo
2      bar
```

then I can sort by the `order` field.

But if I need to insert another name (`newname`) that should be between `foo` and `hello` I need to change the order fields of `hello` and `bar` so the table would be this:

```
order  name
-----------
2      hello
0      foo
3      bar
1      new
```

- Is this approach correct?
- Couldn't the renumbering process be very
  slow if the table contains many rows?
- Are there better approaches for this kind of problems?

Comment: the approach is "natural" (you cannot avoid adding "artificial index" to [sort "nominal" attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement)), but you could improve (re-ordering)... e.g. by choosing not (0,1,2...) but (0,10,20,...) ;)

Comment: Maybe there is another column in the table you may already sort by? Otherwise why would you decide to show new above others?

Comment: @ekochergin it's the end user who decides that `new` should be inserted between `foo` and `hello`.

Comment: that's sad. then I don't see any other solution rather than that one in the answer

Comment: How often would you be inserting or swapping the values and how often would you be doing select ... order by?

Comment: @SalmanA `SELECT... ORDER BY order` : almost all the time. Swapping: not often, inserting: very often.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, renumbering the entire table when you have a new item is probably not a great idea.

One common practice is to keep sufficient gaps in the numbering values so you can insert new values between them. E.g., if you start off with 0, 100 and 200, the new value can easily be 50.
Note that in theory, you could also use floating-point numbers which would give you the ability to insert infinite new values between each value. In practice, the precision the database can store these floating point numbers is limited (depending on the RDBMS and the column definition).

Comment: If you use a gap of 100 and use (a+b)/2 for each insert, if someone repeatedly inserts an item at positon 2 it'll take 6 attempts before you have a problem.